# Unity giving me errors when i try to build my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

i have tried to build my project in Unity. but, i got a lot off error. iam a newbie.
here's my error's

Thank You

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(9,30): error CS0115: 'PlayAudioClipEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(7,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(5,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(5,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CanEditMultipleObjectsAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\BrightAnimator\Runtime\Editor\PlayAudioClipEditor.cs(6,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CanEditMultipleObjects' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 7 seconds (6799 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 7 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <5ad584e208e14caaa9e6b2e6027e9204>:0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Comment: The namespace `UnityEditor` is completely removed when building the app .. strange case though since afaik a script inside a folder `Editor` should be ignored anyway as well ... you can probably Hotfix your issue by wrapping that script with `#if UNITY_EDITOR` (at the top) and `#endif` (at the bottom of your file) preprocessors

Comment: I can see that your class is in a **Editor** folder but I suspect there is a deeper problem going on.  Ensure that **PlayAudioClipEditor.cs** is in the Unity-generated **Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj** and not your main csproj file.  Generally there is no need for the `#if UNITY_EDITOR`.  https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Special_Folder_Names_in_your_Assets_Folder#.22Editor.22

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `UnityEditor` code which is causing these errors. To fix this, you have to add `#if UNITY_EDTIOR` and `#endif` on top and bottom of each editor script respectively.

## Example

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class MyClass: Editor
{
    // Your code
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `#if UNITY_EDITOR` solution is to place an assembly definition file into (each of) your `Editor` folders, and enable ONLY the Editor platform in it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been quite a while since the question was asked, but for me it was different from what was mentioned in the other answers.

I separated my editor scripts into an assembly. Therefore, I had similar errors until I modified "Included Platforms" for this assembly to have only Editor.